# Zig Zag pattern

Tags: flight-planning, private-jets

[image: flight pattern]H

Hi everyone,
has anyone ever seen such a flight pattern ? This plane is doing that every day on different parts of the country (private plane) and I've never seen such a flight pattern before. Any clue ?

Comment: Actually, I could. Of course. But I don't know why, i think I need to keep the 'ID' of the plane quite private for now. I can post here several patterns (screenshots from flightradar24) as this plane (private plane) is doing such type of flights every day....hmmmm. What do you think about it ? And thank you for the reply

Comment: Looks like a typical aerial survey pattern. Very methodical. Without knowing to whom the plane belongs, you can only speculate what they are surveying or for what they are looking. Could be Search and Rescue, damage assessment, seismic research, aerial pesticide (mosquito) spraying, air quality sampling, or one of any number of things. Considering the current environment, it might have something to do with Covid19 research or containment.

Comment: I f I post here the ID, could you track whom the plane belongs ? I'd do that if it's useful

Comment: AIRCRAFT
Rockwell 690A
AIRLINE
Private owner
OPERATOR
-

Comment: If you had the ID, why have you not looked up the owner. You could have answered your own question. Or, at least given those here more with which to work. Private or not, if it is trackable on flightradar24, the operator is not worried about secrecy. I can go to my local airport now and see three or four  different organizations that do this sort of work on a daily basis. You can even google them. For all we know, the flight in question could be mapping for Google.

Comment: "If you had the ID, why have you not looked up the owner" I don't know how to do it ! Otherwise I would have done it...please help ? Thanks

Comment: We posted simultaneously. The info listed in your post does not help. Do you have an ID? Aerial survey companies use planes as small as Cessna 172s to as large as DC-3s. Do you at least know where the plane is based?

Comment: So, here's the ID - Flight history for aircraft - I-BLFE
AIRCRAFT
Rockwell 690A
AIRLINE
Private owner
OPERATOR
-
TYPE CODE
AC90
Code
-
Code
-
MODE S
30052F
SERIAL NUMBER (MSN)
AGE

Comment: So, no offense. It took me 1 minute to pull up hd photos of the aircraft and another minute to google the photography company name on its vert. stab. Since it’s website and Facebook page are in Italian, I gave up on translating it. If you are in Italy, you may get more benefit from the info. Just use Google.

Comment: I'm a newby. So thanks for the hints, I'll do my job now (just didn't know one could search arplanes id :) ) Thank you very much. Photography company......ok !

Comment: By the way, as mentioned before. This looks like your average, run of the mill, aerial survey company. Companies like this fly all day, everyday where I live. Nothing unusual nor nefarious.

Comment: And their website as an English translation option.

Comment: All right, thank you. It was just "weird" that they were flighing right above the areas that have the highest number of coronavirus deaths...................... Just saying. But all right

Comment: No problem. Please feel free to enjoy AviationStackExchange. Generally, you will find the questions and answers here are of more a technical nature. But, we welcome any and all aviation enthusiasts. Add any research you may have already done to your questions so we may best help answer them.

Comment: Weird? It makes sense. Scientists and doctors might want as much info as possible. Anything from environmental temperature readings, humidity readings, ocean and ground water movement, etc. might be helpful in containing this thing. More than likely, this was a scheduled survey planned way before the Coronavirus for a totally different purpose. I would not count out them being hired by Googlemaps to update their database.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was a bit hesitant before posting such a naive question here but hey, I shot the question and you've been very welcoming. Thank you again

Comment: Also, don’t be afraid to ask if a particular flight has to do with a particular situation. Unless you are taking pictures of the people onboard, or the interior of the aircraft, any publicly obtained info on a flight is fair game. Private airports on the other hand are another story. And most plane tracker sites have opt out provisions for private owners to remain anonymous. Putting your reasons for asking also helps us answer the specific question.